# Removing head from a linked list in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

This should be a fairly basic question, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out. I'm using two files given to me by my instructor, and I have to write a method `removeFirst` that will remove the head from a declared linked list and return that old head value. It cannot take any parameters. Here's [file 1](http://pastebin.com/nQN87Sw6) and [file 2](http://pastebin.com/NB2FVQ14).

My code for removeFirst and debugging is below. I do not know how to reference the `aList` without being able to use it as a parameter, especially since the linked list is not global. When I use the debugging code, it prints `aList`, then prints `21` (the head of the list that it should be removing, and which is what `removeFirst` should be returning), but then it does not print the updated linked list -- it's just blank.

`removeFirst` code:

```
public IntNode removeFirst() {
    IntNode cur = getHead();

    head = cur.getNext();
    head.setPrev(null);

    cur.setNext(null);

    return cur;
}
```

Debug code (at bottom of `main`):

```
for(int i = 0; i < aList.size(aList.getHead()); i++) {
    aList.print(aList.findObject(i));
}

aList.print(aList.removeFirst());
System.out.println("");

for(int j = 0; j < aList.size(aList.getHead()); j++) {
    aList.print(aList.findObject(j));
}
```

Comment: Can you please share `getHead()` method and `head` declaration.

Comment: My apologies, I have updated the links so file 1 now links to the correct file. `getHead()` and the `head` declaration are both there.

Comment: I'm confused with your convensions... if you use `getHead()` to retrieve a reference to `head` on `cur` why do you then directly reference `head` on the next line?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how linked lists and all of the object references work together, which is why some of it is really messy. What should it be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `return head;` instead of `return cur;`

**EDIT** Sorry. I evidently misunderstood your problem statement. The above is appropriate if the `removeFirst()` method is supposed to return the *new* head of the list. If it's supposed to return the removed element (as is clear now after your comment and edit of the original post), then it should be working properly.

Presumably `removeHead()` is an instance method in your list class. You don't need to pass a parameter because the list is available as `this` inside the method.

It would help to see the class definition for `aList`. Your `file 1` link says it's to MyLinkedList.java, but the pasted code there is for IntNode.java.

**EDIT 2** The problem, I think, may be your debug code. `findObject(j)` does not return the `j`<sup>th</sup> element of the list--it returns the list element that contains `j` as a value. From the code, it looks like `MyLinkedList.print(IntNode)` prints the entire list starting at the indicated node. What happens if you replace the `for` loops in your debug code with simply:

```
aList.print(aList.getHead());
```

Comment: That causes it to be removed (the second for statement does print it without the head), but with that code it no longer prints out the value being removed. What does this change that makes it work? I don't understand.

Comment: Shoot, I phrased my initial question incorrectly. It needs to return the value that it is removing, so cur needs to be returned. The problem is that it doesn't do anything to the existing list -- it won't print the updated list afterward.

**EDIT** I apologize, I updated file 1's link so it's now the correct file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you doing all fine except the return. You need to return `head` in place of `cur` as `cur` is representing the removed `head` node(previous one).

```
public IntNode removeFirst() {
    IntNode cur = getHead();

     head = cur.getNext();
     head.setPrev(null);

     cur.setNext(null);

     return head;
 }
```

**EDIT:** Since you have updated your question, here is the answer of your second question;

**You can refer `aList` using `this` operator.**

Update: I added `removeFirst()` method in your `MyLinkedList` class as it is then I added these thwo statements in your method (in the end)

```
    aList.removeFirst();
    aList.print(aList.getHead());
    System.out.println("");
```

It works correctly and prints the output as:

```
    84 88 92 96 100 
    100 96 92 88 84 
    Size = 5
    Adding another IntNode
    21 84 88 92 96 100 
    Adding yet another IntNode
    21 52 84 88 92 96 100 
    The object is 92
    The object containing 50 was not found.
    The object removed has 96 in it.
    The object containing 50 was not found. Nothing was removed.
    21 52 84 88 92 100 
    Removing Head
    52 84 88 92 100
```

Comment: Shoot, I phrased my initial question incorrectly. It needs to return the value that it is removing, so cur needs to be returned. The problem is that it doesn't do anything to the existing list -- it won't print the updated list afterward.

Comment: @StevenH As I requested in the comment, can you please share some more sections of your code?

Comment: @StevenH: Did you use `this` operator to refer the `aList`? If please share more code sections.

Comment: @StevenH: I don't see `removeFirst` method in your `MyLinkedList`. What is it implemented?

Comment: The `MyLinkedList` file is the file we were given. It is its own method at the bottom of the class.

Comment: @StevenH: I am looking at your link. I don't see `removeFirst` method. Where is it?

Comment: @StevenH: I see you have already accepted the answer, but jut wanted  to share that your code was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption would be that since you're accessing all your Objects *by reference* you are essentially destroying your list as you execute the `removeFirst()`

```
IntNode cur = getHead();
```

same as

```
cur = head;
```

As they're accessible in the same scope. By doing this when you execute:

```
head.setPrev(null);
...
cur.setNext(null);
```

you're basically doing this:

```
head.setPrev(null);
...
head.setNext(null);
```

or....

```
null <-- head --> null
```

See where this is going?

What you're aiming to do is get a copy of the node you're removing and then destroying that copy's reference to the list.

```
IntNode cur = new IntNode(getHead().getVal());
```

and when you're trying to remove the old head from the node:

```
head.setNext(head.getNext());
head.setPrev(null);
```

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense and really helps. Thank you!